# Retrieving main and secondary functions of an employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The relation between my tables Employee, Function and Company is located in `[Employee_Scope]`
In `Employee_Scope` we have an order column called `[SortOrder]`.
Main Function is the function in the scope where `SortOrder != NULL and SortOrder = MIN(SortOrder)` for a specific employee.
Secondary functions are the rest.

**Example :** 
[image]

Here the Main functionId is “1”. 
Secondary functionId is 54. 
The function itself can be found in `[Employee_Function]` table.

I already extracted all the functions with the following query :

```
SELECT [le].[EmployeeId], [le].[FunctionId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [le].[EmployeeId] ORDER BY [le].[SortOrder] ASC) AS [RealOrder] 
        FROM (
              SELECT [e].[EmployeeId], [es].[FunctionId], ISNULL([es].[SortOrder], 0) AS [SortOrder]
         FROM [dbo].[Employee] [e] 
                 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employee_Scope] AS [es]  ON [es].[EmployeeId] = [e].[EmployeeId]
                  WHERE es.SortOrder != NULL
                    HAVING es.SortOrder !=MIN(es.SortOrder) ) [le]
```

The output of the previous query:

[image]

Now I need to get separately, the main function and the secondary ones for each employee so I tried the following to get the main function :

```
SELECT [le].[EmployeeId], [le].[FunctionId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [le].[EmployeeId] ORDER BY [le].[SortOrder] ASC) AS [RealOrder] 
                     FROM (
          SELECT [e].[EmployeeId], [es].[FunctionId], ISNULL([es].[SortOrder], 0) AS [SortOrder]
         FROM [dbo].[Employee] [e] 
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employee_Scope] AS [es]  ON [es].[EmployeeId] = [e].[EmployeeId]
        WHERE es.SortOrder = (SELECT MIN(es1.SortOrder) FROM Employee_Scope es1)
                 ) [le]
```

**Expected output :**

For EmployeeId = 5205

```
EmployeeId FunctionId(Main) CompanyId SortOrder
5205       1                20        1

EmployeeId FunctionId(Secondary) CompanyId SortOrder
5205       1                     50        30
5205       54                    154       60
```

Comment: So you need to replace the value for `SortOrder` `1` with `0` in your end results as well? Now it just looks like you need to use `WHERE SortOrder = 1` and `WHERE SortOrder > 1`.

Comment: The sortOrder can change from an employee to another. For employeeA, sortOdrer can be 100,45,7 . so the main function will be the one having the sortOrder = 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reading this and see this as the logic:

For the main function:

```
where sortorder = 0
```

For the secondary ones:

```
where sortorder > 0
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

If you want the minimum, to be the "main" rows, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employeeid order by sortorder) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Then use `where seqnum = 1` or `where seqnum > 1` depending on which you want.